# tmuxinator does not update session after editing that session's project

Tags: tmuxinator

I have a tmuxinator project `some-project`.

After using it, I updated it with `tmuxinator edit some-project`.
Now when I run `tmuxinator start some-project`, I get the same session layout as before editing `some-project`.

How can I make tmuxinator use the new project version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmux kill-session -t some-project
tmuxinator start some-project
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

kill the session first using:

`tmux kill-session -t some-project`

then start the project again using:

`tmuxinator start some-project`